# remove single object from an svg created with Javascript

Tags: jquery, svg, visibility

I have created an "iphone style" toggle button using svg in javacript. Code Follows:

```
var btnsvg;
var aCircle;
var aTextOn;
var aTextOff;

function circle_click(evt) {
    var circle = evt.target;

    if ($(circle).position({ svgCx: 20 })) {
        $(circle).animate({ svgCx: 50 }, 400);
        $(aTextOn).animate({ svgFillOpacity: 1.0 }, 400);
        $(aTextOff).animate({ svgFillOpacity: 0.0 }, 400);
    }
    else {
        $(circle).animate({ svgCx: 20 }, 400);
        $(aTextOn).animate({ svgFillOpacity: 0.0 }, 400);
        $(aTextOff).animate({ svgFillOpacity: 1.0 }, 400);
   }
}

function drawToggleButton() {

    $('.toggleButton').each(function () {
        btnsvg = $(this).svg().svg('get');
        btnsvg.linearGradient('btnGrad',
            [[0, '#000000'], [1, '#000000', 0.32]], 50.168, 28, 50.168, 3,
            { gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'
            });
        btnsvg.linearGradient('offGrad',
            [[0, '#1F1F1F'], [1, '#A2A1A1']], 32.6685, 28, 32.6685, 3,
            { gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'
            });
        btnsvg.linearGradient('onGrad',
            [[0, '#1A2D49'], [1, '#304866']], 32.6685, 28, 32.6685, 3,
            { gradientUnits: 'userSpaceOnUse'
            });
        btnsvg.rect(10, 10, 50, 20, 10, 10,
            { fill: 'url(#offGrad)', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1
            });
        aCircle = btnsvg.circle(20, 20, 10, { onclick: 'circle_click(evt)', fill: 'url(#btnGrad)' });

    });
}
```

It sort of works...

Problem 1
Both words show at first, The opacity allows me to change on the animate but does not allow me to set as an intial attribute. I'd really like to remove the text all together (aTextOn = visible, aTextOff = notVisible) But I will settle for the opacity for now. I also tried

```
$(aTextOff).text({fill: 'rgb(0,0,0,0.0)'});
```

that didnt work either

Problem 2
Only works on the first click... No clue why this is happening!

Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks

ps. if you have an tips on a smooth transitioning gradient change as well.. that would be cool too.

Comment: I don't know if you wanted a 'plain' JS solution, but if libraries are an option, I strongly suggest D3.js. See http://blog.visual.ly/creating-animations-and-transitions-with-d3-js/ for an example of opacity transitioning.

Comment: Kinda wanted to do it with out a plugin... See solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for the opacity... I was trying to set it initial using

```
$(aTextOff).text({fill: 'white', svgOpacity: 1.0});
```

But it should have been

```
$(aTextOff).text({fill: 'white', opacity: 1.0});
```

'svgOpacity' is for animation while 'opacity' is for attributes http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

I also moved the circle so that it was created after the text and therefore would be on top. As for the click function, I created a property on the div where the svg button is rendered to tell me what the state(true/false) is then based on that animated the circle and text to create the toggle effect. code follows:

```
 function circle_click(evt) {
    var circle = evt.target;      
    var currentState = $('.toggleButton').attr('value') == 'true';

    if (!currentState) {
        $(circle).animate({ svgCx: 50 }, 400);
        $(aTextOn).animate({ svgOpacity: 1.0 }, 400);
        $(aTextOff).animate({ svgOpacity: 0.0 }, 400);
    }
    else {
        $(circle).animate({ svgCx: 20 }, 400);
        $(aTextOn).animate({ svgOpacity: 0.0 }, 400);
        $(aTextOff).animate({ svgOpacity: 1.0 }, 400);
    }

    $('.toggleButton').attr('value', !currentState);

}
```

before I was trying to use the position by calling the following

```
$(circle).position({ svgCx: 20 });
```

but that sets the position as opposed to checking to see if that is the position.

Still no solution for the gradient... Coming soon....... I HOPE

Solution for the gradient animations....

I added an other rect with a new grey scale gradient with the opacity set low and put it on top of the original rectangle.

```
 aRect = btnsvg.rect(10, 10, 55, 20, 10, 10,
   { fill: '#606060', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1
   });
   btnsvg.rect(10, 10, 55, 20, 10, 10,
   { fill: 'url(#myGrad)', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 1
   });
```

'aRect' is the one that I animate the color on and with the transparent gradient on top, gives the illusion that the gradient is changing..

```
$(aRect).animate({ svgFill: '#1A2D49' }, 400);
```